# Error after build app - Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Request works at development, but gives me and error after build

I'm having trouble fetching data when building my app.
It works great with `yarn dev` but `yarn start` gives me an error

I'm using proxy to an API as the [docs says](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development). I understand this is for dev only. How it should be done for production?

This is yarn dev:

[image]

This is yarn start:

[image]

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "yarn build && npx serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://ip/ler.com",
```

fetching data:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchArtigos = async () => {
        try {
            const resp = await GetArtigos()
            const artigos = resp.map(artigo => {
                artigo.publishedAt = trataData(artigo.publishedAt)
                return artigo
            });
            setArtigos(artigos);
            setIsisLoaded(true);
        }
        catch (erro) {
            console.log('erro');
            console.log(erro);
            setErro(erro);
            setIsisLoaded(true);
        }
    }
    fetchArtigos()
}, [])

return (
    <div className="container-cards">
    <div className="grid-cards">
        {artigos.map((artigo, index) => (
            <Card
                key={index}
                item={artigo}
            />
        ))}
    </div>
</div>
)
```

service.js

```
export const GetArtigos = async () => {

    const response = await fetch('/blog');
    const artigos = response.json();

    console.log('artigos');
    console.log(artigos);

    return artigos;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think we'd need to see the codebase before we could begin to help you; this is a very limited amount of information and an extremely vague error code

Comment: thank you, I tried to add what I think is the relevant part of the code

Comment: get rid of this line in the react component: `/* TODO loading */` and retry it

Comment: let me know when you've tried it; I have a gut feeling it is the issue. Make sure to rebuild the app

Comment: I took it off, same thing. Does proxy work at build version? But I don't think is that, cause it would be another error, or the request should not even work. I'm editing the question

Comment: what is the endpoint returning? you'd probably want to share the network tab information for the requests

Comment: it returns some minified js and css. If I try to make a call directly from my code (without proxy), I get a CORS error. I really don't think the endpoint should be at proxy in package.json

Comment: yeah, you probably need to setup proper cors settings on the API server

Comment: I have no access to this server, is another person job. But thanks, I will just talk to him and make the request directly from service.js